Are the "elect angels" in 1 Timothy 5:21 born-again believers?
1 Timothy 5:21 ESV

In the presence of God and of Christ Jesus and of the elect angels I
charge you to keep these rules without prejudging, doing nothing from
partiality.

Are the "elect angels" transfigured saints?
Apostle Paul notes that there physical bodies and spiritual bodies, and that born-again believers are adopted sons of God; germinating angels, gods.

"germinating angels"? People don't turn into angels. (There are denominations that believe people's human spirits can become "impregnated" by God's holy spirit at baptism, and the resulting spirit is an embryonic god, developing perfect character until it can be reborn as an immortal spirit, but I'm not aware of any denomination with a doctrine stating that people turn into angels. That's a TV meme.)

Elect angels are all those angels and archangels who kept themselves in this position of being created spirits continuously kindled by love of God and praisingly contemplating His eternal glory, “the mighty in strength who carry out His word” (Psalm 103:20), unlike their fallen counterparts, who became demons, because they “did not keep their own domain, but abandoned their proper abode” (Jude 1:6).
From this passage we see that Christ, together with God, is absolutely not enclassed in the class of angels and far less of their fallen counterparts, and since there is nothing higher in creatures than angels, therefore Christ is above creatures, and since above creatures is only Creator and Creator is only God, therefore Christ is Creator of angels and the entire universe, alongside with God-Father, being Himself God.

"Elect angels" is a unique term...

@JoshuaB As only the elect humans inhabit and will  inhabit eternal Kingdom (Matthew 22:14), so only the elect angels inhabit the same Kingdom, the rest are fallen angels, demons.

Levan - If angels are called "sons of God", and we are adopted as "sons of God", and called such by Christ, does this mean that being "born from above" and being "not of this world" man that we become like the angels themselves as immortal spiritual bodies to join God's angelic family?

+1. Good answer - I also notice that it is the saved who sing the song of Moses and the Lamb (Rev 15:3, 14:3) that the angles cannot learn

@Dottard Thank you!

@JoshuaB We are not the same creatures as angels, we, humans, although possess an aspect of the angelic nature, for we also have a God-loving rational, contemplative souls and we also can through those features reach angelic heights; however, we are still dearer to God than angels are, and that’s why God, the Logos, became man, not angel, to herald this greater intimacy to us than to the highest of angels. Angels are ministers in the Eternal Kingdom, we, on the contrary, are kings, the co-kings with the Eternal King - Christ, through the Latter’s grace.

Levan - Jesus was an angel too, according to Galatians 4:14 and Philippians 2:6, along with all of the Angel of YHWH passages as well as Malachi's "Angel of the Covenant" who intercedes for man to God and comes into his temple.

@JoshuaB As to OT text, you are right, sometimes the Logos of God, the pre-Incarnate Christ is sometimes called “angel”, but the same Person featuring in the sentence as subject, is alternately called both “Lord” and “Angel”, like in the episode with Moses worshipping  the one who speaks to him from the burning bush, who is called alternately “angel” and “lord”. Moreover, no angel can have a self-sovereign authority of forgiving or not forgiving, it is only God’s prerogative, and since this Angel has this prerogative, He can be only of equal dignity with God, thus also God and worship-due.

@JoshuaB Galatians 4:14?! Are you kidding?! On the contrary, this passage proves superiority of Christ over angel, for Paul uses here a rhetorical trope called “climax”; If I say, “Luisa was so hospitable, that she received me as if I were a duke, as [even] Charlemagne!” In this sentence is climax and strengthening of meaning, and as preposterous is to think that the Emperor Charlemagne is duke, so utterly preposterous is to think Paul calls Christ “angel” in Gal 4:14.

Levan - Jesus is called the "Son of God", and fellow angelic brothers are called "sons of God".

@JoshuaB He is called “Son” in a unique way: μονογενης means “unique”, “the only-brgotten”. The Logos/Son is born from the Father naturally/essentially, eternally, pre-creatorially. The angels are creatures, they worship the Son, how can angel worship another angel?

I'll stick with Guthrie's understanding of the term, as referring to those angels who are chosen or "commissioned" to watch over the affairs of men:

The mention of these elect angels is surprising, but may be due to the belief that they are commissioned to watch over men’s affairs. There may also be an eschatological reason, reminiscent of the Lord’s words in Luke 9:26.1


26 “For whoever is ashamed of Me and My words, the Son of Man will be ashamed of him when He comes in His glory, and the glory of the Father and of the holy angels. (Luke 9:26 NASB95)

Chrysostom also links back to the OT, taking the elect angels as being those who watch from above:

But wherefore the elect Angels? From great moderation, as Moses said, “I call heaven and earth to witness” (Deut. 4:26).2


1 Donald Guthrie, Pastoral Epistles: An Introduction and Commentary, vol. 14, Tyndale New Testament Commentaries (Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity Press, 1990), 121.
2 John Chrysostom, “Homilies of St. John Chrysostom, Archbishop of Constantinople, on the First Epistle of St. Paul the Apostle to Timothy,” in Saint Chrysostom: Homilies on Galatians, Ephesians, Philippians, Colossians, Thessalonians, Timothy, Titus, and Philemon, ed. Philip Schaff, trans. James Tweed and Philip Schaff, vol. 13, A Select Library of the Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers of the Christian Church, First Series (New York: Christian Literature Company, 1889), 464.

What if it refers to the heavenly angels and earthly germinating angels? (God's chosen ones)

@JoshuaB. One would need more than this single verse to develop a theology of "germinating angels." Matthew 22:30 says that at the resurrection they will will be "like angels (ὡς ἄγγελοι)," in the sense of not marrying. The passage specifically does not say that they will become angels.
